# Showing Error in Range of Auto fill command by giving range of Active cell to Last row of the column

Tags: excel, vba, range, autofill

I'm facing this issue i just want to enter the data in user form-text box and that value have to auto fill from the row to the last row of the column B. with this code i having error with range from active cell to the lastrow of the column. find the last line of the code range.kindly issue out this problem.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim irow As Long
Dim activeworksheet As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long


    irow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    lastrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Set activeworksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("master sheet")

    With activeworksheet

    .Cells(irow, 1) = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

    .Cells(irow, 1).Select

    Selection.range(range("Activecell"), range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)).FillDown


    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it just this that you need? Not sure I fully understand.

```
With activeworksheet
    Range(.Cells(irow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 1)).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
End With
```

Comment: I need a autofill range for the above command the error was showing in the last line of the code. For range of activecell to lastrow sir

Comment: Why do you need autofill, this single line does the same thing?

Comment: that line is not working, i checked and i need to upload the value in textbox so that every time it will be store in that column i already have data on column next so its need to fill down upto the lastrow of the column from the activecell entered..so this code will run continously..now i need a range command for fill for that to fill from te activecell to the lastrow